# what is burst vertex and what it is meant to be in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I have a vertex which I want to delete from the graph. After trying in so many ways to delete it, I got to know that it is a burst vertex. I need help in understanding the burst vertex.

Comment: You say that you learned that it's a burst vertex, but you don't know what a burst vertex is? So, how did you get to know that it's a burst vertex? Do you maybe simply mean a supernode, e.g., a vertex with a very high number of edges?
It would also help if you could show what you have tried to delete the vertex and how it failed exactly.

Comment: I haven't learnt burst vertex. I said that,this vertex is a burst vertex.One of my seniors said that it is a burst vertex which means If the vertex is stable for one month then it will get deleted automatically.But when i searched for it in online I haven't found anything.

Comment: [already tried code for deleting a vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690223/how-to-delete-the-unmodifiable-vertex-which-has-no-edges-in-gremlin). this vertex is parent node with high number of edges.